# Determine the mean and autocovariance function of xt, and state whether it is stationary

Tags: time-series

I'm trying to understand the process to answer this question.

> Let $w_t,$ for $t=0, \pm1, \pm2,...$ be a normal white noise process, and consider the series:
>
> $x_t=w_tw_{t-1}$
>
> Determine the mean and autocovariance function of $x_t$, and state whether it is stationary or not.

Can someone explain to me behind this logic:

$\gamma_x(h)=Cov(x_t,x_{t+h})=Cov(w_tw_{t-1},w_{t+h}w_{t+h-1})=\sigma^4_w $

Comment: $x_t$ is stationary, since $w_t$ is stationary.  $y_t$ is undefined.  Assuming you meant $x_t$, the formula for $\gamma$ doesn't look right. If the $w_t$ are independent then the $cov=0$.

Comment: sorry $y_t$ is a typo

Comment: What about cov?

Comment: the cov is not a typo. if we assume h=0, what should we get?

Comment: For $h=0$, the expression is correct, being the product of two variances.  For $h\ne 0$, $cov=0$, assuming independence for $w_t$ with different $t$.